# Codename one date picker issue

Tags: java, arrays, oop, codenameone

I have created a custom calendar where I am trying to call picker whenever I am clicking on calendar button, but it can't work for me, Following is my application code, which is not working properly. So how can I modify this code so I am able to call picker from ActionEvent?

```
    public class PivDisplayCalendar extends Container {


    int length =37;
     private ComboBox year;
     private static final String[] DAYS = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
     private static final String[] LABELS = {"Su", "M", "Tu", "W", "Th", "F", "Sa"};

     private ArrayList<Button> allButtons = new ArrayList<Button>();
     //Button newButton = new Button("");

    public PivDisplayCalendar(){

        super(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            Container calendarTitle = new Container(new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER));
            Container title = new Container(new GridLayout(1,7));
            Container days = new Container(new GridLayout(6, 7));
            Container calendarTitleCopy = new Container(new GridLayout(1, 1));
                calendarTitleCopy.setUIID("CalendarTitleCopy");
            this.addComponent(calendarTitleCopy);
            this.addComponent(title);
            this.addComponent(days);


            Button prevMonth = new Button("<");
            Button nextMonth = new Button(">");
            SpanLabel monthYear = new SpanLabel("Month " + " Year");
            calendarTitle.add(BorderLayout.WEST, prevMonth);
            calendarTitle.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, monthYear);
            calendarTitle.add(BorderLayout.EAST, nextMonth);
            calendarTitleCopy.add(calendarTitle);
            Button dayButton= new Button();




           if(UIManager.getInstance().isThemeConstant("calTitleDayStyleBool", false)) {
                title.setUIID("CalendarTitleArea");
                days.setUIID("CalendarDayArea");
            }
            for (int iter = 0; iter < DAYS.length; iter++) {
                title.addComponent(createDayTitle(iter));
            }
            for (int iter = 1; iter < length; iter++) {
               dayButton = new Button(""+iter);

                    dayButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                            Log.p("Action event triggered");
                            Picker datePicker = new Picker();
                            datePicker.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_DATE);

                            //Button b1 = (Button)(evt.getActualComponent());
                            //Log.p( b1.getText() );
                        }
                    });

               allButtons.add(dayButton);
                days.addComponent(dayButton);
                if (iter <= 7) {
                    dayButton.setNextFocusUp(year);
                }
            }              
    }


     protected Label createDayTitle(int day) {
        String value = getUIManager().localize("Calendar." + DAYS[day], LABELS[day]);
        Label dayh = new Label(value, "Label");
        dayh.setEndsWith3Points(false);
        dayh.setTickerEnabled(false);
        return dayh;
    }
}
```

**This is my application screenshot:-**

[image]

**And following method is used for event handling:-**

```
for (int iter = 1; iter < length; iter++) {
               dayButton = new Button(""+iter);

                    dayButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                            Log.p("Action event triggered");
                            Picker datePicker = new Picker();
                            datePicker.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_DATE);

                            //Button b1 = (Button)(evt.getActualComponent());
                            //Log.p( b1.getText() );
                        }
                    });

               allButtons.add(dayButton);
                days.addComponent(dayButton);
                if (iter <= 7) {
                    dayButton.setNextFocusUp(year);
                }
            }
```

Comment: what is it doing? is there any error message/exception? Pls include the calendar button action code.

Comment: I have updated the question. @lupz

Comment: Ah, sorry! I think I got you wrong on the first sight. But I am still confused... As far as I understand the code there is a button for each day of a month (as shown in the screenshot). So you want to show a datepicker after the user picks a date (selects/touches a day-button)? Couldn't you set/use the selected day/date right away? Anyways, the action code might be missing something to actually show the picker. At least in the [codenameOne Picker javadoc-example](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/spinner/Picker.html) they add the picker to a Form and call `show()` on that.

Comment: Yes, I was also checking out that example, but I don't want to add additional control to the form. That's why I am not including Form.show() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code creates a `Picker` component, but doesn't add it to any form or display it.  Probably what you are looking for is [`Display.showNativePicker()`](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Display.html#showNativePicker-int-com.codename1.ui.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-), as this will simply pop up a native picker dialog.

You should first check to see if the platform supports a native picker (only iOS and Android have native pickers), and create your own dialog with a `DateSpinner` component in it.  Check out the [source for the Picker class](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/ui/spinner/Picker.java#L73-L192) to see an example of how it does this.

Comment: Thanks Steve it helps me a lot And I am doing this project for Android as well as for IOS so this will be the ideal solution for my project. @steve hannah